# Potential energy of a Dipole interaction unexplained sign error.

Tags: physics

[image]

[image]

Hello i've attactched a question as well as my attempt at an answer, I get the correct mathematical expression however I have a sign error for both the terms in the bracket. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong to have caused these errors to arise. Help please!

Comment: You need not have changed angle for the second dipole, if the angles are described the way they are its best just to leave them

Comment: But when I take the projections of the vector p2 I need the acute angle between the vectors? Also that still leaves me with a sign error on the sine term? Have I got the directions of the components of the E field at 2 correct (sketch top right) ? I was unsure at the direction of the theta unit vector

Comment: You would only need the acute angle if you had used the second definition of dot product, since you are using the primary definition of multiplying components (i.i or j.j) its unimportant how the angle is measured

Comment: Also yes the sketches are fine, Im just saying leave the positives or negatives buried in the trig terms, ie if a field component is negative it will be a result of taking the sine or cosine of the angle, youre answer is actually correct, the sign is a result of measuring your angles from two different spots